# JQuery: Better way than queue:false or div wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

Here is my situation. I'm trying to do several animations on a single element at once; however, with the UI thread 'feature' and JQuery's animation queue it's becoming a hassle.

I'm designing a re-usable control library for a site and one of the things I wanted to do was to have a multi-class attribute system to initiate different animations upon `ready()`.

For instance:

```
<div class="fadein loadingbar"></div>
```

with the CSS for an image background for `.loadingbar`, and then JQuery to animate the loading-bar's background indefinitely:

```
$(".loadingbar").each(function(){
            $(this).css({backgroundPosition:"0px 0px"});
            $(this).animate({backgroundPosition:"(-65px 0px)"}, (($(this).height() / 35) * 2000) + 600, "linear", function(){_n3_animLoadBars(this)});
        });
```

as well as the `fadeIn()` animation for the `.fadein` class:

```
$(".fadein").each(function(){
       $(this).css({opacity:0,visibility:"visible"})
       .animate({opacity:1}, {duration:1000});
    });
```

However; the only way to get them to animate asynchronously is to do `{queue:false}` for the `.animate()` function, which works fine until I want to *delay* the fade-in animation:

```
$(".fadein").each(function(){
           $(this).css({opacity:0,visibility:"visible"})
           .delay(800)
           .animate({opacity:1}, {duration:1000,queue:false});
        });
```

which completely skips the `.delay()` call since it's not queued (therefore not placing the animation cue right after the delay on the fx stack).

The only fix is to wrap the div with another div:

```
<div class="fadein"><div class="loadingbar"></div></div>
```

and to take the `{queue:false}` out, of course.

---

While this works, the javascript was supposedly going to be advanced enough so the markup didn't have to be that messy (usually a simple div wrap like that is fine with me, but I'm designing this for my own personal amusement and **I would like to keep it down to a single div** if at all possible).

Any quick fix with JQuery that I am missing, or is there a way to do this through writing a plugin?

Any insight would be helpful!

Comment: Just to clarify you want the opacity and progress of the loading bar to be sync'ed?

Comment: Yes - so the `.animation()` calls for both the classes, as well as the `.delay()` call for the `$(".fadein")` block, if that makes sense.

Comment: So at the same time, the animation for the .loadingbar class fires and plays, as well as the delay call for the .fadein class fires and waits at the same time; and then *after* the delay is up, while the first animation is still playing, the fadein animation for the element occurs asynchronously.

Comment: And ^this^ happens all on the same element.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a jsfiddle for me to utilise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution - it was easier than I thought.

Instead of specifying `{queue:false}` on the fade-ins, I specified it on the background animations, leaving the fade-ins queued.